# Recreating a sentence from its positions

Tags: python

```
sentence= raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)
position = [word for word in range(len(uniquewords))]
```

I have the position of the uniquewords, the uniquewords and the sentence. I need now to recreate the original sentence with the positions of each word for example: `I LIKE PYTHON PYTHON PYTHON LIKE HI`

This would be recreated to `1 2 3 3 3 2 4`. The uniquewords mean the word "`PYTHON`" can be repeated as many times as it likes without affecting the position of "`HI`" and making it in position 7 can someone please help me with recreating the original sentence with the position of each word.

Comment: I think you need to use a dictionary rather than a list for `uniquewords`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower().split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])

print positions
print recreated
```

take note that in this implementation, position starts at `0` and not `1`.

Comment: @two1234 good to hear! Will you accept this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You first of all need a good string tokenizer, to split the phrase in tokens in the right way. A good string tokenizes comes with [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).

```
macbookproloreto:~ admin$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence="I LIKE PYTHON PYTHON PYTHON LIKE HI" 
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['I', 'LIKE', 'PYTHON', 'PYTHON', 'PYTHON', 'LIKE', 'HI']
>>>
```

As soon as you have `tokens` you have the positions as array indexes, so you can do your iterations.

At this point we create a `set` of unique words:

```
>>> unique=set(tokens)
>>> unique
set(['I', 'PYTHON', 'HI', 'LIKE'])
```

We then turn it into a list

```
>>> list(unique)
['I', 'PYTHON', 'HI', 'LIKE']
```

We know match position in the original tokens array i.e. the original sentence, so:

```
>>> indices = [tokens.index(t) for t in tokens]
>>> indices
[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 6]
```

That is your original sentence:

```
>>> original = " ".join([tokens[t] for t in indices])
>>> original
'I LIKE PYTHON PYTHON PYTHON LIKE HI'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I don't know if it's because you program is unfinished or wrong but but position result in `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and not `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3]`.

Here is a completed version of your program that work and construct back the sentence from position.
I have rename position in digitSentence:

```
sentence= raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)
wordToNum = {uniquewords[word]: word for word in range(len(uniquewords))}

digitSentence = map(wordToNum.get, sentence)

print digitSentence

print ' '.join(map(uniquewords.__getitem__, digitSentence))
```

Comment: exactly it starts from `0` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just iterate through the position array and use the index of uniquewords. Something like:

```
reconstructed = []

for i in position:
  reconstructed.append(uniquewords[i])

print " ".join(reconstructed)
```

should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Is position ouput?

```
sentence= raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.split()
count = 1
uniquewords = {}
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords[word] = count
        count += 1
position = [uniquewords[word] for word in sentence]
```